# Como melhorar consideravelmente a segurança do Apache?

Tags: php, apache, segurança, ddos

Estou configurando um servidor web utilizando o Apache. Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Quais módulos eu utilizo para melhorar a segurança contra ataques e acessos mal intencionados nas páginas publicadas no meu servidor?

Sei que existem vários módulos, mas, qual a melhor solução?

Comment: Você pode instalar algo no servidor não como módulo Apache, mas sim um firewall como o CSF (http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) ?

Comment: A título de curiosidade: já trabalhei com servidores Apache que usavam [anti-virus](http://www.clamav.net), [proxy reverso](http://nginx.org) e outras tecnologias. Não funcionavam pois como eram mal configurados no primeiro acesso do PHP ao sistema de arquivos acabei encontrando dados sigilosos da hospedagem. Não é só usar módulos, mas configurar bem, ainda mais o sistema, como citei.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você precisa ter um conhecimento dos módulos que seu sistema vai usar. Deixe ativado somente o minimo necessário para que seu sistema funcione, não deixe pontas soltas.

Você também precisa ficar atento as noticias de vulnerabilidade e bugs nos módulos pelos quais você optou. Por exemplo o modulo rewrite, um dos mais usados em urls amigáveis e outros fins, teve a vulnerabilidade [VU#395412](http://www.rnp.br/cais/alertas/2006/USCERT-VU-395412.html) a poucos anos atras.

Essa pesquisa de vulnerabilidades e aplicação de pacotes de segurança precisa ocorrer pelo menos mensalmente mas dependendo do quão critica é aplicação o intervalo precisa ser menor. Isso também não deve se limitar ao Apache mas a qualquer programa que estiver instalada em seu servidor.

Além disso algumas coisa básicas que ajudam na segurança do apache.

**- Esconda a versão do apache e mensagens de erro.**

Para  um cracker saber a versão de um programa é equivalente a saber a quais vulnerabilidades e ataques este programa esta sujeito. A mensagens de erros costumam passar informações comprometedoras como portas usadas e pastas do sistema. Desative isso no httpd.conf.

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

**- Desative a lista de diretórios**

Ao acessar-mos um diretório de um sistema pelo navegador podemos obter uma lista dos arquivos dessa pasta. É a famosa página "Index of/". Você precisará, no httpd.conf, de algo  como o seguinte para evitar esta listagem:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

**- Não de permissões de root para o apache**

O apache não precisa ter permissão para acessar e modificar todos os cantos do sistema. mantenha isso o mais apertado possível somente o necessário para o funcionamento.

**- Usar Allow e Deny para restringir o acesso aos diretórios**

Provavelmente em alguns lugares essas regras precisarão ser afrouxadas mas forneça acesso somente onde ele é necessário.

```
 <Directory />
   Options None
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</Directory>
```

**-Modulo Security**

O mod_security funciona como um firewall e nos permite monitorar o tráfego em tempo real. Também ajuda a proteger contra ataques de força bruta. Foi criado por Ivan Ristic em 2002 e tem sido mantido atualizado pela empresa Trustwave e é totalmente OpenSource.

**mod_evasive**

Combate ataques de DDOS. Segundo a descrição do próprio autor do modulo:

"mod_evasive é um módulo para o Apache de manobras evasivas, fornecendo um desvio em caso de DoS HTTP, ataque DDoS ou ataque de força bruta. Ele também é projetado para ser uma ferramenta de detecção e gerenciamento de rede que pode ser facilmente configurada para conversar com ipchains, firewalls, roteadores, etc."

**Abilite o modulo de Log**

Logs oferecem informações valiosíssimas sobre o que acontece no sistema em termos de segurança e outros problemas.

**Considerações Finais**

A regra básica é manter tudo o mais simples e "apertado" possível, se os programas e módulos do seu servidor incharem muito a administração poderá ficar muito complexa, o acompanhamento de bugs e malwares pode se tornar algo epopeico, as vulnerabilidades também irão aparecer de forma diretamente proporcional a este inchaço. Siga os princípios "KISS" (Mantenha isto estupidamente simples) e "YAGNI" (Você não irá precisar disto).

Answer (score 5):

Trazendo uma resposta mais consistente e atualizada sobre o assunto, porém, sem descartar tudo que @raonibs disse, atualmente o mod_security é suficiente para te proteger contra ataques **DoS** e **Brute force**. Então você pode economizar em mais um modulo e se desfazer do mod_evasive, que hoje é um módulo desatualizado.

## Ratelimit e DoS Protection

Depois de muitos testes, monitoramento e estudos, criei a regra abaixo, o funcionamento é simples, primeiro **limita** o acesso a 1 por segundo quando o acesso passa de 1000 conexões no minuto (este é um valor alto para evitar falso/positivo, mas você pode editar de acordo com sua infra-estrutura), envia o erro **429** e `Retry-After` para alertar bots de pesquisa e informar para tentar novamente após 10 segundos. Se o ataque DoS continuar, derruba a conexão por 60 segundos.

Em suma, este código é um ratelimit com proteção contra DoS.

Funciona muito bem, foi testado com as ferramentas de stress mais conhecidas. Mas não tem efeito sobre ataques DDoS, e pode ter um efeito negativo em alguns casos de ataques em larga escala (mas esse é um assunto para outro tópico).

```
# Ratelimit - DoS Protection
SecAction initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},pass,nolog,id:'5000750'
# conta requisições por segundo por ip
SecAction "phase:5,id:'5000751',deprecatevar:ip.rlimit=1/1,pass,nolog"

# ignora requisição de localhost ou algum outro ip
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^123\.45\.67\.89$" "phase:1,id:'5000740',nolog,allow"

# se as requisições passarem de 100 (var dos>100), derruba a conexão (útil se você usa algum proxy, tipo cloudflare)
SecRule ip:dos "@gt 100" "phase:2,id:'5000752',pause:300,drop,setenv:RATELIMITED,skip:2,log,msg:'IP address blocked - DoS Attack'"

# se as requisições passarem de 1000 (var rlimit>1000), nega a conexão e retorna http 429, e aumenta a var dos em um (expira em 60 segundos)
SecRule ip:rlimit "@gt 1000" "phase:2,id:'5000753',pause:300,deny,setvar:ip.dos=+1,expirevar:ip.dos=60,status:429,setenv:RATELIMITED,skip:1,nolog"

# aumenta a var rlimit em um (expira em 30 segundos)
SecAction "phase:2,id:'5000754',pass,setvar:ip.rlimit=+1,expirevar:ip.rlimit=30,nolog"

Header always set Retry-After "30" env=RATELIMITED

ErrorDocument 429 "Too Many Requests. Calm down!"
```

## Brute Force

Abaixo é um exemplo de regra para proteção contra Brute force no Wordpress, existem muitos exemplos espalhados pela internet, fiz algumas modificações nesse código para funcionar nas versões mais recentes do mod_security e diversos testes, incluindo com a famosa ferramenta [WPscan](https://wpscan.org/). Também funciona muito bem.

```
<Locationmatch "/wp-login.php">

    # Setup brute force detection.
    # React if block flag has been set.
    SecRule user:bf_block "@gt 0" "deny,status:401,log,id:5000135,msg:'ip address blocked for 5 minutes, more than 15 login attempts in 3 minutes.'"

    # Setup Tracking.  On a successful login, a 302 redirect is performed, a 200 indicates login failed.
    SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^302" "phase:5,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0,id:5000136"
    SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^200" "phase:5,chain,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=+1,deprecatevar:ip.bf_counter=1/180,id:5000137"
    SecRule ip:bf_counter "@gt 15" "t:none,setvar:user.bf_block=1,expirevar:user.bf_block=300,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0"

</locationmatch>
```

Você pode alterar `/wp-login.php` para qualquer página que quiser proteger.

## SYN Flood

Também criei uma proteção contra SYN Flood e DoS para apache usando **iptables**, compatível com **WHM** e especialmente para quem usa **CSF**.

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables -N BLOCK_IP
/sbin/iptables -N SYN_CHECK
/sbin/iptables -N DOS_CHECK
/sbin/iptables -N SYN_ATTACK
/sbin/iptables -N DOS_ATTACK
#
# primeiro verifica se o IP esta bloqueado
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j BLOCK_IP
# derruba se estiver bloqueado
/sbin/iptables -A BLOCK_IP -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m recent --name BlockedIP --rcheck --seconds 30 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A BLOCK_IP -p udp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m recent --name BlockedIP --rcheck --seconds 30 -j DROP
# se passou o tempo desbloqueia
/sbin/iptables -A BLOCK_IP -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m recent --name BlockedIP --remove -j RETURN
/sbin/iptables -A BLOCK_IP -p udp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m recent --name BlockedIP --remove -j RETURN
#
# verifica: se existe mais de 100 conexões simultâneas com status SYN - ignora IP do gateway
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 --syn ! -s 123.45.67.89 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 100 -j SYN_CHECK
# verifica: conexão feita e posteriormente a frequencia - ignora IP do gateway
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 ! -s 123.45.67.89 -m state --state NEW -j DOS_CHECK
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dport 80,443 ! -s 123.45.67.89 -m state --state NEW -j DOS_CHECK
#
# verifica se o ataque é frequente (no caso de erro: --hitcount não pode ser maior que 100 - aumente o limite de pacotes em ip_pkt_list_tot.conf)
/sbin/iptables -A SYN_CHECK -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 70 --name RATE -j SYN_ATTACK
/sbin/iptables -A DOS_CHECK -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 70 --name RATE -j DOS_ATTACK
# caso o ataque seja frequente, bloqueia por 30 segundos e gera log
/sbin/iptables -A SYN_ATTACK -j LOG --log-prefix "BLOCK SYN ATTACK: " --log-level 6
/sbin/iptables -A SYN_ATTACK -m recent --set --name BlockedIP -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A DOS_ATTACK -j LOG --log-prefix "BLOCK DOS ATTACK: " --log-level 6
/sbin/iptables -A DOS_ATTACK -m recent --set --name BlockedIP -j DROP
#
# se o ataque não é frequente, libera
/sbin/iptables -A SYN_CHECK -m recent --set --name RATE -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A DOS_CHECK -m recent --set --name RATE -j ACCEPT
#
```

Muitas pessoas utilizam o **fail2ban** para proteger contra SYN Flood, porém, nem sempre usar fail2ban é algo simples, especialmente para quem já usa CSF. Esse script foi testado e até a data desta postagem, funciona muito bem. Ele funciona para complementar os SYN cookies, que devem estar ativados em seu sistema operacional.

Para rodar é muito simples, basta acrescentar o código nas regras do seu iptables `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, ou se você usa CSF basta colocar em `/usr/local/csf/bin/csfpre.sh` e digitar no terminal `csf -r`.

## Anti-Slowloris

Para proteger o Apache contra Slow DoS ataques, você deve usar o plugin mod_reqtimeout, eu uso a configuração abaixo, 10 segundos com 1 segundo acrescido a cada 500 bytes à espera de uma conexão é suficiente na maioria dos casos, são raros os falso/positivo:

```
<IfModule mod_reqtimeout.c>
   RequestReadTimeout header=10-40,MinRate=500 body=10,MinRate=500
</IfModule>
```

A regra abaixo para mod_security foi tirada da internet (e é opcional, apenas mod_reqtimeout já é suficiente), mas funciona muito bem contra esse tipo de ataque, deve ser usado em conjunto com ModReqtimeout.

```
SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "@streq 408" "phase:5,t:none,nolog,pass,
setvar:ip.slow_dos_counter=+1, expirevar:ip.slow_dos_counter=60, id:'5000770'"

SecRule IP:SLOW_DOS_COUNTER "@gt 5" "phase:1,t:none,log,drop,
msg:'Client Connection Dropped due to high number of slow DoS alerts', id:'5000771'"
```

A regra acima identifica quando o servidor HTTP dispara um código de status 408 e rastreia quantas vezes isso aconteceu enquanto mantém os dados em armazenamento persistente com base no IP para que ele possa correlacionar entre as solicitações. Se esse evento acontecer mais de 5 vezes em 60 segundos, solicitações subsequentes para esse endereço IP serão descartadas pelo mod_security por um período de 1 minuto.

## Mas, preste atenção!

### Balançadores, Varnish Cache, Nginx

Se sua infraestrutura possui balançadores, Varnish Cache, Nginx ou qualquer outro tipo de gateway, você vai precisar usar o **mod_remoteip** e configurar o `X-Forwarded-For` corretamente no cabeçalho para o apache conseguir enxergar o IP real do usuário, do contrário, as regras acima não irão funcionar e podem acabar bloqueando o IP do seu gateway.

Também é importante saber que você precisa criar ratelimits para o seus gateways, apesar da minha regra derrubar a conexão indesejada, no caso do gateway, se ele for ignorado pela regra (o que é o correto), a requisição vai passar e só durante resposta do apache que a conexão será derrubada, não impedindo um ataque DoS (mas poupa recursos do processamento da página, o que é bom de qualquer forma).

### Cloudlare

Se você usa ou pretende usar [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), você também pode configurar o IP real do usuário usando o mod_remoteip através do cabeçalho `CF-Connecting-IP`, ou usar o mod_cloudflare.

### Firewall

É muito interessante você possuir um Firewall para trabalhar com o mod_security, eu recomendo o CSF (Configserver Security & Firewall).
Com ele basta definir o `LF_MODSEC =` no arquivo de configuração.

O valor de configuração `LF_MODSEC` é o número de 'hits' necessários para adicionar o IP ofensivo a ser bloqueado pelo firewall. Definir `LF_MODSEC` como 5 seria bloquear o endereço de IP após 5 bloqueios no mod_security dentro do período de tempo definido em `LF_INTERVAL`, que é definido em uma hora (3600 segundos) por padrão.